# Azure DevOps SSH Service connection not working with IPV6

Tags: .net, azure-devops, ipv6

I need to publish my .NET bundle to a Ubuntu 22.04 VPS.
The VPS has only one static IPV6 address and it's normally working with ssh by macOS terminal connection.

This is the azure DevOps pipeline task that generate the error:

```yaml
- task: SSH@0
  displayName: Prepare copy publish artifacts on remote machine
  condition: and(succeeded(), in(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main', 'refs/heads/develop'))
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'My VPS'
    runOptions: 'commands'
    commands: |
      mkdir $(pipelinesFolder)/$(Build.BuildNumber)
    readyTimeout: '20000'
```

and that's the error:

```
Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Error: connect ENETUNREACH my-static-ipv6-address:22 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4062, code: 'ENETUNREACH', syscall: 'connect', address: '5a00:fd42:1312:1c00:0000:0000:0000:0028', port: 22, level: 'client-socket' }.
```

(I removed the real IPV6 address)

I simply fill the service connection "hostname or IP" field with my IPV6 address (without braces or other custom constructs).

How can I solve the problem? Does the Azure DevOps service connection supports IPV6?

I've already worked a lot of time with ssh service connection using IPV4 with no problems.

Comment: IANA has set aside the `2001:db8::/32` IPv6 address range for example IPv6 addresses (you can subnet it any way you like), just as they set aside the `192.0.2.0/24`,`198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24` IPv4 address ranges for example addresses. That way people can tell they are examples. The address you have, `5a00:fd42:1312:1c00:0000:0000:0000:0028` is a reserved address that you cannot use on the Internet. Remember that hosts get RAs from the router to tell them which networks the router supports and the gateway (router's link-local address) for those networks.

Comment: Hi @RonMaupin, this is not the real address, I changed it with fake number and letters. So thank you for your consideration but normally with the real one I can connect normali with ssh using my pc as all the other IPV4 address

Comment: When faking a real address, you are supposed to use an address in the `2001:db8::/32` address range that IANA has set aside for things like this so that people can tell right away that is is an example address. I am not sure why you chose to ignore that and use something in a reserved range that may be assigned to something else in the future.

Comment: For "fake address" I mean that simply I don't want to publish my real address on Stack Overflow. The real one starts with `2a00:6d42` and it is released from a public VPS service, so I think it is ok.

Comment: Exactly, and that is why we have the `2001:db8::/32` address range. When you use that, people know that is is not your real address because you do not want to publish the real address.